# CakePHP 3: save new entity (Error: Integrity constraint violation)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I make a new cakephp app but I have an error for several days.

This is the database structure:

```
Articles:
id | title | user1 | user2
--------------------------

Users:
id | username | email
----------------------
```

ArticlesTable.php:

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('Articles');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('User1', [
           'className' => 'Users',
           'joinType' => 'INNER',
           'foreignKey' => 'user1',
           'propertyName' => 'user1'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('User2', [
           'className' => 'Users',
           'joinType' => 'INNER',
           'foreignKey' => 'user2',
           'propertyName' => 'user2'
        ]);
     }
}
```

ArticlesController.php:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();

    }

    public function index() {
        $this->paginate = ['contain' => ['User1', 'User2']];
        $articles = $this->paginate($this->Articles);

    }

    public function add() {
        $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data);
            debug($article);
            debug($this->request->data); die;
        }
    }
}
```

Article.php

```
class Article extends Entity {
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true
    ];
}
```

All the articles are displayed on the web page. (with index() on the ArticlesController)

The problem is when I call add() in the ArticlesController:

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add        or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`articles`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`user1`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

Can someone explain me the error?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
This is the output data:

```
[
    'title' => 'xxxxxx',
    'user1' => 'xxxxx',
    'user2' => 'xxxxxx'
]

object(App\Model\Entity\Article) {
    'title' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
     ],
     '[dirty]' => [
         'title' => true
     ],
     '[original]' => [],
     '[virtual]' => [],
     '[errors]' => [],
     '[invalid]' => [],
     '[repository]' => 'Articles'
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the `debug($this->request->data);` ? =]

Comment: Post edit with more information.

Comment: In your request data, the values in user1 and user2 are their IDs? You need to provide user1's ID in the request data, and the same thing for user2.

Comment: Yes, they are IDs. They are present.

Comment: That's not neccessarily the problem here, but do not use the same name for `propertyName` and `foreignKey`, this is guaranteed to cause problems at some point, as both are ment to be able to exist in the same dataset/entity at the same time, and one is supposed to hold an entity/dataset itself, and the other an identifier.

Comment: Note that this message is coming from MySQL, not Cake itself. Google the error text and you should find lots of results explaining the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have already searched on Google, this is the first thing I do... I solved my error with this:    $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data(), ['associated' => []]); 
It's not logical with what is in the doc but it works. 
Normally, I should have put the names of aliases. Thanks for all your answers.